# Which allreduce algorithm is used for large vectors (200MB+) in OpenMPI (V2.0.2)?

Tags: algorithm, mpi, openmpi

Currently, I am trying to understand the details of the MPI_Allreduce for large vectors in the OpenMPI (version 2.0.2). I have learned allreduce algorithms like binomial tree, recursive doubling, recursive halving and doubling, binary block, and the ring algorithm. Most of them are based on the reduce-scatter and then allgather.

But I am still wondering which allreduce algorithm is used for large vectors (200MB+) in OpenMPI (v2.0.2). It would be great to provide details about it.

Really appreciated : )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is in the code, see `ompi_coll_tuned_allreduce_intra_dec_fixed` in https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/v2.0.2/ompi/mca/coll/tuned/coll_tuned_decision_fixed.c

short answer, it depends
longer answer, it depends on your communicator size, the datatype/count you are using (e.g. one derived datatype for a large vector, or many predefined datatypes) and whether your operator is commutative or not.

you can also ask Open MPI with `mpirun --mca coll_base_verbose 1 ...` (that being said, i think you need to have Open MPI configure'd with `--enable-debug` in order for this to work)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works! (i.e. I have 4 processes to perform the allreduce on float vectors. Each process owns its float32 vector with 648010 elementes, which is about 2.47MB. The native sum operation is used to perform the allreduce on these 4 vectors. It turns out to be the "coll:base:allreduce_intra_ring" algorithm. Great ! Just as the source code said.) However, when I change to my "user-defined reduce operation" (which is also element-wise sum, just I coded myself instead of the native sum.), the mpi printed out two algorithms! "ring" and "recursive doubling". Is there some secrets? Thanks

Comment: if you can make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve i will be happy to have a look at it. if you created your own operator with `MPI_Op_create()`, make sure you declared it as commutative, otherwise `coll/tuned` will likely choose an other algorithm

Comment: Appreciated for your help! I just confirmed that with my user-defined sum and commutative=true, the allreduce only prints out the "ring" algorithm, just as the native sum allreduce. Here is my code in my google drive: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxuk2nyTbdcTMjQ0SUNlck9hWWc/view?usp=sharing). However, this raises an another question: is my user-defined sum allreduce the same as the native sum allreduce in terms of the implementation algorithm? Thanks again : )

Comment: note the C++ bindings were removed from the MPI standard. they are still available in most MPI libs, but maybe not for so long. you can use plain `C` bindings, or have a look at Boost::MPI (i do not use C++, but this lib has a good reputation). as long as the operator is commutative, the communication pattern involved in allreduce does not depend on a custom vs native operator, so in your case, you can stick with the native one. Generally speaking, keep in mind that using `MPI_IN_PLACE` might force MPI to choose a different algorithm (mainly to keep memory footprint low)

Comment: Thanks a lot! : )

Comment: Very informative! May I have one more question about the "Ring Allreduce"? I read the code and found that the ring allreduce performs the ring-based reduce-scatter followed by the ring-based allgather. However, it says the allgather is a [variation of ring allgather](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/e291d0eeed4d4626a2f44c96127b9629713bd969/ompi/mca/coll/base/coll_base_allreduce.c#L496). How is it different from the [regular ring allgather](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/e291d0eeed4d4626a2f44c96127b9629713bd969/ompi/mca/coll/base/coll_base_allgather.c#L362)?

Really appreciated!

Comment: Have already figured out "the variation of ring allgather". Thanks anyway.

Comment: BTW, @GillesGouaillardet ,would it be convenient to look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45680016/what-is-segmented-ring-allreduce-in-openmpi-v2-0-2-how-is-it-pipelined