# What is Segmented Ring Allreduce in OpenMPI (V2.0.2)? How is it pipelined?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I have been trying to understand the [**Segemented Ring Allreduce**](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/blob/e291d0eeed4d4626a2f44c96127b9629713bd969/ompi/mca/coll/base/coll_base_allreduce.c#L618) in OpenMPI (V2.0.2). But I failed to figure out this pipelined ring allreduce, especially how the phases are pipelined. (i.e. COMPUTATION PHASE 1 (b) seems to perform the two phases concurrently instead of "pipelinely".) Could MPI experts provide the motivation behind this Segmented Ring Allreduce and details about the pipeline?

Really appreciated,
Leo

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this has been asked and answered at https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues/4067

very specific questions regarding the internals of Open MPI, are better asked directly to the Open MPI mailing list(s) or [github repository](https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi)